Change broken wire from socket of standing lamp
Attached image of socket . I couldnt figure out how to remove two end of wire from socket. Wire is broken and I would like to install new wire in this socket.
If you attached any video link or thread will be thankful to you
Please help me . Thank you

why do you show two views of the socket end and no views of the sides?


Is there a release mechanism on the side of the socket? 2. Are the wires soldered or crimped in place?


It is possible that you will have to replace the socket; cheap ones may have the wires crimped in place during assembly.

There is a pin on the side but couldn’t move the pin.. if you look at the second picture (black one)

BTW, 3-way lamp sockets, such as shown, are shown on Amazon, for example, for ~US$3. However, if I were replacing the cord and socket, I'd opt for an ordinary socket with dimmer for LED lamp, or remote-dimmable LED.
